# Replacing only single "\n" in string occurrence

Tags: c#, string

I have a string in C# which can have multiple `\n` characters. For e.g. :

```
string tp = "Hello\nWorld \n\n\n !!";
```

If there is a single occurrence of `\n` I want to replace it with something, but if more than one `\n` appear together in the same place I want to leave them alone. So for the `tp` string above I want to replace the `\n` between `Hello` and `World`, because there is only one at that place, and leave the the three `\n` nearer the end of the string alone, because they appear in a group.

If I try to use the `Replace()` method in C# it replaces all of them. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which occurrence of `\n` are do you need to replace?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching.

Comment: Re-opened. This was not a duplicate of the chosen answers. It's not about "first" occurence, it's about appearing in a group. Edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I agree, this should be allowed in my opinion

Comment: To actually address the question... I'd normally use RegEx for this, but I'm not sure what that looks like for the \n character in .Net's regex engine, so I'll leave a full answer with code to someone else.

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(tp, "\n+", match => match.Value.Length > 1? match.Value : "*");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *regular expressions*: let's change `\n` into `"*"` whenever `\n` is single:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

... 

string tp = "Hello\nWorld \n\n\n !!";

// "Hello*World \n\n\n !!";
string result = Regex.Replace(tp, "\n+", match => 
  match.Value.Length > 1 
    ? match.Value // multiple (>1) \n in row: leave intact
    : "*");       // single ocurrence: change into "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using loops:

```
char[] c = "\t"+ tp + "\t".ToCharArray();
for(int i = 1; i < c.Length - 1; i++)
  if(c[i] == '\n' && c[i-1] != '\n' && c[i+1] != '\n')
    c[i] = 'x';
tp = new string(c, 1, c.Length-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *regular expressions* and combine [negative lookbehind and lookahead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#grouping-constructs):

```
 var test = "foo\nbar...foo\n\nbar\n\n\nfoo\r\nbar";
 var replaced = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(test, "(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)", "_");
 // only first and last \n have been replaced
```

While searching through the input the regex "stops" at any `"\n"` it finds and verifies if no `"\n"` is one character behind the current position or ahead.
Thus only single `"\n"` will be replaced.